# How to attach a function to Dropdown.Toggle on React Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to execute a function when my React Bootstrap Dropdown.Toggle is clicked.

I tried adding `onClick` like the following but that breaks the dropdown functionality altogether and doesn't show the dropdown menu on click:

```
<Dropdown>
  <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic" onClick={myFunction}>
    Dropdown Button
  </Dropdown.Toggle>

  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

Is there any way of preserving the original functionality of the toggle and still executing an additional function when it is clicked?

Comment: Can you show what is inside myFunction?

Comment: You can define a custom toggle function. This is as per the documentation of React Bootstrap Dropdown: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/#custom-dropdown-components

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're overriding the inbuilt onClick, maybe you can attach the event listener on the `Dropdown` itself and check whether it was triggered from the button.

```js
      <Dropdown
        onClick={e => {
          if (e.target.id === "dropdown-basic") {
            //do something
          }
        }}
      >
        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
          Dropdown Button
        </Dropdown.Toggle>

        <Dropdown.Menu>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, the mistake I made was, I was using onClick in dropdown.Toggle. So I just moved my onClick into Dropdown and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

```
   const onSelect = (eventKey, event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.persist();
        event.stopPropagation();
     console.log(eventKey) // selected event will trigger
    }



 <Dropdown className="d-inline mx-2" onSelect={onSelect}>
    <Dropdown.Toggle id="dropdown-autoclose-true">
      Default Dropdown
    </Dropdown.Toggle>

    <Dropdown.Menu>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1" href="#">Menu Item</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2"  href="#">Menu Item</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.ItemeventKey="3"  href="#">Menu Item</Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>
```